# Is use of std::vector<T*> less safe than std::vector<shared_ptr<T>>?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Say I have a simple data class:

```
struct Foo
{
   int iData;
   double dData;
};
```

I can create a container class that could be implemented as:

**Version 1**

```
struct Bar
{
   std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>> fooData;
};
```

or as:

**Version 2**

```
struct Bar
{
   Bar(){}

   Bar(Bar const& copy)
   {
      for(auto fooPtr: copy.fooData)
      {
         fooData.push_back(new Foo(*fooPtr));
      }
   }

   ~Bar()
   {
      for(auto fooPtr: fooData)
      {
         delete fooPtr;
      }
   }

   Bar& operator=(Bar const& rhs)
   {
      if ( this == &rhs )
      {
         return *this;
      }

      for(auto fooPtr: fooData)
      {
         delete fooPtr;
      }
      fooPtr.clear();  // Had missed this in the original code.

      for(auto fooPtr: rhs.fooData)
      {
         fooData.push_back(new Foo(*fooPtr));
      }

      return *this;
   }

   std::vector<Foo*> fooData;
};
```

Granted that **Version 1** is a lot simpler and easier to maintain than **Version 2**.
However, I have couple of questions that are orthogonal to that aspect of the code.

1. Is **Version 1** safer than **Version 2** from the point of view of dealing with exceptions?
2. If so, how?

Comment: Why not `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @MooingDuck, will that make a difference to the issue of dealing with exceptions?

Comment: Not in the slightest.  However, it's faster than `std::shared_ptr`, and I find it simpler to reason about.

Comment: Your assignment operator has a bug. You don't clear the vector before adding new elements. Is that a good enough answer to your question? Manual memory management is not easy to get right.

Comment: In the `shared_ptr` version, the objects are shared, whereas in version 2, they point to different things. Additionally, you miss out on the free move constructor that you get in Version 1.

Comment: @Praetorian That comment is worthy of a dozen upticks. Alas I have but-one to offer.

Comment: How can you look at the massive difference between both code snippets and still wonder which one is better? Version 1 is way shorter, handles all the cases correctly for you, and is overall much safer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the first option is more exception safe.  Namely, your copy constructor has two memory leak sources, the copy assignment operator has a memory leak and is simply plain wrong.  Additionally, the first option has move assignment and a move constructor by default, giving improved performance.  (Even more performance if you used `std::unique_ptr` instead)

```
Bar(Bar const& copy)
{
   for(auto fooPtr: copy.fooData)
   {
      fooData.push_back(new Foo(*fooPtr));
      //what happens if `new Foo` throws a bad_alloc?
      //or if `Foo(const Foo&)` changes and now throws something?
      //or if `fooData.push_back` throws a bad_alloc?
      //anything you 'new'd is leaked.
   }
}

Bar& operator=(Bar const& rhs)
{
   if ( this == &rhs )
      return *this;

   for(auto fooPtr: fooData)
      delete fooPtr;
   //You forgot this line:
   //fooData.clear();

   for(auto fooPtr: rhs.fooData) //sharth notes you wrote copy.fooData but that's obvious
      fooData.push_back(new Foo(*fooPtr));
      //what happens if `fooData.push_back` throws a bad_alloc?
      //the `Foo` you just created is leaked.

   return *this;
}
```

Comment: How does `std::vector<T>::operator=()` deal with `bad_alloc` resulting from `push_back()` or does it not use `push_back()` at all?

Comment: In the same vein, how do `std::vector<T>`'s member functions deal with `bad_alloc`? Does the standard mandate that `vector`, and other other STL containers, deal with exceptions in a sane way?

Comment: @RSahu: Each function is different.  Many functions are "if an exception occurs, no change is made to the container".  Some are "if an exception occurs, some the container and data are valid, but may not be the data that you necessarily wanted."  There's a _tiny_ number that say "undefined behavior if exceptions occur" (mostly destructors and such).

Comment: @RSahu: I know that `operator=` allocates all the memory upfront, but I can't recall if it's a "no changes if exception" or "unspecified data if exception".  Probably the second, for performance reasons. [Edit: Actually, sometimes it's one, sometimes the other, depending on the allocator types. STill researching]

Comment: § 23.2.3 says `operator=`... "Assigns the range `[il.begin(),il.end())` into `a`. All existing elements of `a` are either assigned to or destroyed." I can't find further detail, but it's safe to assume it does a resize, then a series of assignments.  A really smart implementation might only resize down, do assignments, then push_back up to size.  However, I can't find guarantees in the spec as to exception guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 and version 2 have different semantics.  If you copy a Bar object, version one gives shared access to the data, while version 2 does not.  Version 2 also has a subtle memory leak; if `new` succeeds while `push_back` fails, the object leaks.

Why not use the even simpler `std::vector<Foo>`?  I'm not seeing any rationale for using pointers (either shared or raw) in this case.  Value semantics are much, much easier to reason about than pointer semantics.

Comment: The main question for which I was looking to an answer involves allocating objects from the heap. `Foo` was just an example class to use in the containers.

Comment: vector<Foo> does allocate its objects in the heap.  I see no justification for the extra complexity in your code of having vector manage pointers to Foo objects instead of having vector manage Foo objects themselves.  It cannot be polymorphism (the usual reason), because the copy code you wrote in version 2 would then be horribly broken.  I see no other reasons (other than perceived performance, but you'd have to measure that) from a code clarity point of view.  Could you elaborate on why you believe it is better to have vector manage pointers than to have it manage objects directly?